# Why do we use Session ID cookies on the web instead of a unique device identifier?

Tags: web-browser, session-management

Session IDs aren't exactly secure, you can copy them from one device to another just by copying the browser's temp files. Techniques to tell apart one device from another have existed in browsers for a while, for example [this here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDeviceInfo/deviceId).

Sure you could change your mac address, make the browser spit out different information to impersonate another device through extensions or recompiling the source, but that seems so much harder and more secure than storing the session in a file on a PC that's not necessarily trusted. This way could be entirely server-side too.

Is there genuinely some reason I'm missing, or have conventions not caught up for unique device ID to be preferable to session ID?

Comment: For MediaDeviceID, the user would be prompted to allow access to their microphone and/or camera. (ID is also generated per session) Most users wouldn't understand that prompt in the context of a standard login.  It's important to note that a session is only a session and is not an authentication method.  The authentication is a separate concern.  Some sites do in fact, indirectly, tie authentication to the hardware when they create/pass certificates.  (DPAPI, Chrome cert, etc...) But they need a program installed to do that.  Most sites don't have that privilege.

Answer (score 1):

While the deviceId is specific to the origin, it is not specific to the current user and its status on this site (like logged in or not) and it does not expire. So it is impossible to have different users on a site, limiting the lifetime of a session and implementing logging in and out - at least impossible without additional methods like a session id.

Therefore the deviceId should not be used instead of the session id. It can be used in addition to the session id though in order to make sure that the session id is valid for the current device.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't consider the possibility of having multiple users on the same device. Verifying session ID with device ID seems to have all the pros without any cons

Answer (score 0):

> Session IDs aren't exactly secure

Secure against *what*, though? Who is the attacker here, what access do they already have, and what are they trying to do?

- If you're thinking of the attacker as the legitimate user (you're trying to prevent them from presenting different clients as the same one, for some reason), then obviously this doesn't achieve anything except inconvenience for them; anything that the legit client would send, a spoofed one could duplicate.
- If you're thinking of an attacker who gained access to the browser's data store while offline, modern major browsers encrypt that data with a user-specific key, so unless the attacker had the legitimate user's login password, it wouldn't do them any good.
- If the attacker has online access to the data store (e.g. malware running in the user's account), they can make the browser generate/return the same ID string that is used for device ID, and steal that for later impersonation (though this would be a substantial speed bump for the attacker, right up until anybody wrote a quick automation script for it which would happen quickly if this approach caught on).

There is room for some security improvements around the edges - HTTP clients that aren't major browsers, or platforms like desktop Linux where there's not guaranteed to be a secure way to encrypt user data - but you still have to deal with the issues that Steffen raised, which adds complexity, so I don't expect this approach to become popular even if it might see some niche use.